# Rebuild some code to return damage or miss based on probability (game)

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm trying to implement fight and accuracy based on probability. Here is my code but it doesn't work quite well.

```
public String setAttackedPartOfBodyPercent(String probability) {
    return this.probability = probability;    // from 0% - 100%
}

private int generateDamage() {
    int miss = generateMiss(probability)+1);
    damage = (new Random().nextInt(30 + getStrength()) + 1) * miss;
    if (damage == 0)
        gs.canvas.drawText("miss", (float) gs.chibi1.getX(), (float) gs.chibi1.getY(), pt.pBlack);
    return damage;
}

public int generateMiss(int accuracy) {
    if (accuracy < 100) 
        return new Random().nextInt((100 / accuracy)+1) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: `Here is my code but it doesn't work quite well.` please explain what do you mean with this ? what are you trying to achieve, what is your current output and what is your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is

```
   public int generateMiss(int accuracy) {
        if (accuracy == 100) return 1;
        return (new Random().nextInt(101) < accuracy) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```